# How to handle the final state in experience replay?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn, experience-replay

I'm using the DQN algorithm to train my agent to play a turn-based game. The memory replay buffer stores tuples of experiences $(s, a, r, s')$, where $s$ and $s'$ are consecutive states. At the last turn, the game ends, and the non-zero reward is given to the agent. There are no more observations to be made and there is no next state $s'$ to store in the experience tuple. How should the final states be handled?

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate of [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/15918/2444).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not store a terminal state as $s$ in the replay table because by definition its value is always $0$, and there is no action, reward or next state. There is literally nothing to learn.

However, you may find it useful to store information that $s'$ is actually a terminal state, in case this is not obvious. That is typically achieved by storing an additional **done** boolean component. This is useful, because it allows you to branch when calculating the TD target **g**:

```
s, a, r, next_s, done = replay_memory_sample()
if done:
  g = r
else:
  g = r + gamma * max( q(s') )
```